polars cross without reversed or equal entries
I'm joining two identical columns and am only interested in combinations (not permutations). Currently, I can perform a full cross-join and, subsequently, filter out the unwanted rows.
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(3)})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"b": np.arange(3)})

expected_output = df1.join(df2, how="cross").filter(pl.col("a") < pl.col("b"))

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┘

Is there a way to do this without generating all combinations in the first place?

There is no extra functionality for these kind of non-equi joins in polars. Your proposed solution seems idiomatic to me. I've also compared with inequality joins in duckdb, but there does not seem to be an advantage.

I would suggest you use some form of binary search - sort the right column, do a binary search on it with the left column and finally gather your final results, either as a list, or exploded. Should be more performant than doing a cross join followed by a filter

The current approach would benefit from the lazy/streaming engine: df1.with_row_index().lazy().join(df2.with_row_index().lazy(), how="cross").filter(pl.col("index") < pl.col("index_right")).collect(streaming=True)

@jqurious, the lazy approach you suggested still uses a cartesian join, which algorithmically is not efficient, compared to sorting and binary search (n2 vs (nlogn)

As you are joining column on itself and if it has unique values you can use:

sort() to sort the values.
rolling() to accumulate values into lists.
explode() to create final dataframe.

import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(3)})

(
    df.sort("a")
    .rolling(index_column="a", period=f"{df.height}i", offset="0i")
    .agg(pl.col("a").flatten().alias("b"))
    .explode("b")
    .drop_nulls()
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┘

Not sure it's going to be more performant though.

.join_where() has since been added which can replace the cross join.
(df1
   .lazy()
   .with_row_index()  
   .join_where(df2.lazy().with_row_index(), 
       pl.col.index < pl.col.index_right
   )
   .collect() # streaming=True?
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬─────────────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ a   ┆ index_right ┆ b   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---         ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ i64 ┆ u32         ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════════════╪═════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0   ┆ 1           ┆ 1   │
│ 0     ┆ 0   ┆ 2           ┆ 2   │
│ 1     ┆ 1   ┆ 2           ┆ 2   │
└───────┴─────┴─────────────┴─────┘

